# How to the remove verbs in a table from a postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I have table called "photos". Which contain three columns like below.

```
photos
photo_id    photo_name          description
--------    ----------          -----------
1            imag1.jpeg          i like restaurant
2            imag2.jpeg          i like dog
etc
```

here my question is while storing images in to a table. How to remove the verbs in a description column.

OUTPUT

```
photo_id    photo_name          description
--------    ----------          -----------
1            imag1.jpeg          restaurant
2            imag2.jpeg          dog
etc
```

Comment: All verbs? `like/dislike/hate/love/...`? Also `I/you/he/...` is not a verb

Comment: Does all the rows in column `description` starts with `i like` or what ?

Comment: i need  to kept description only noun

Comment: `update photos set description=split_part(description,'like',2)`.
**This works if every values in `description` column contains  _like_ word**

Comment: description contains different data .. i had given some sample data

Comment: show some other possible types of data in that column

Comment: Is  it possible to identify the nouns in postgresql

Comment: 2014063556;    "The ambiance is a big plus for this place. It is a breezy rooftop with candlelit tables in the evening.
I was not happy with the service because it was extremely slow. Also, I felt that the attendants needed training because they seemed a tad bit confused (...)"

Comment: Oh!!  its too long, What could be the possible output for this  ?

Comment: Read this - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-debugging.html

Comment: by using full text search will remove stop words. but i identifying the nouns only  problem

Comment: This is really a complex question - how to remove verbs (only) - requires semantic analysis of text to do _properly_.  It may be much easier to white list nouns. Personally, I would not use a dbms to do this type of analysis - I might keep the dictionary in the database - but I would use an application to do this.

Comment: Is  there any functions  to identify the nouns  in postgresql